# How can I copy my world to my server without losing my stuff?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have been playing Minecraft bedrock edition with my friends using XBL, and I wanted to set up a server so I don't have to be online for them to play.

I have gotten the server setup, and I have the world set up to the server, but when I join, I don't have my stuff, and I'm recognized as a new player to the world, I would think it saves your player info to the world file with your XUID, but that's not the case.

Is there a way for it to recognize me as the player I was? Or will I just have to get everyone to store stuff in their chests before I copy it to the server?